# Tutorial to create low poly car

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

I dont find any good tutorial to make a low poly car. I lose 2 weeks just to find an tutorial but nothing and I dont know what to do now. Can you help me as a text answer or pdf file or video. If he could help me, I would be very grateful.
This is for my mobile game.

Somne exemple:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address raised the issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: Requests for tutorials are off topic here. As it stands this question is too broad to be answerable without requiring an extensive tutorial or description. You should show efforts towards reaching your goal, describing what you have tried and why it failed, so we don't risk recommending something you already know. The scope should also focus on a particular step you encountered an issue with. Describing the whole procedure from start to finish would be too lengthy to explain, and is beyond the goal of this site.

Comment: There are quite a lot of good tutorials about "low poly" cars on youtube. Choosing a "good" one is tied to peoples own opinions and their skill level. StackExchange isn't exactly a discussion forum to look for recommendations, you might want to try blenderartists.org